# Using jq how can I replace the name of a key with something else

Tags: json, jq

This should be easy enough... I want to rename a few keys (ideally with jq), whatever I do seems to error though. Here is a json example below:

```
[
 {
  "fruit": "strawberry",
  "veg": "apple",
  "worker": "gardener"
 }
]
```

I'd like to rename the veg key to fruit2 (or example, whatever is easiest) and also the worker key to job.

I realize this is possible in sed, but I'm trying to get to grips with jq

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use the following ***jq*** approach:

```
jq '[.[] | .["fruit2"] = .veg | .["job"] = .worker | del(.veg, .worker)]' file
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "fruit": "strawberry",
    "fruit2": "apple",
    "job": "gardener"
  }
]
```

Comment: Or use map instead, `jq 'map(.fruit2 = .veg | .job = .worker | del(.veg, .worker))' file`

Comment: How would I do the same thing but in an object?

Answer (score 33):

The key (:-) is with_entries.  E.g., given a single object:

```
with_entries(if .key == "veg" then .key = "fruit2" else . end)
```

In your case, since you have an array of objects, you could wrap the above in `map( ... )`.

---

Note that if the original JSON object already has a key named "fruit2", then the usual "last-most wins" rule applies, where in this case, "last-most" refers to the array of key-value pairs that is used to determine the final result (as per the def of `with_entries`).

Comment: this one is great ! How do you do with multiple keys ?

Comment: One way is to extend the argument to with_entries, e.g. with_entries( if .... end | if ... end)

Comment: Notice: use target original value while target fields already exists. eg: `echo '{"veg":[1,2,3], "fruit2":["hello"]}' | jq 'with_entries(if .key == "veg" then .key = "fruit2" else . end)'`   result: `{ "fruit2": [ "hello" ] }`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to use [`if-then-else-end`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#if-then-else-end) with `elif` to rename multiple keys:

```
map(with_entries(.key |=
  if . == "fruit"  then "fruit2"
elif . == "worker" then "job"
else . end))
```

<sup>(jqplay [example](https://jqplay.org/s/4LgHVFT_sb-))</sup>

Note in the current development branch / upcoming 1.7 release the empty `else` branch will be optional and could be removed, but it's still required in v1.6.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to manipulate the `key` with a value from `value`:

```
$ echo '{ "foo": {"id": 123}, "bar": {"id":456} }'  | jq 'to_entries | map({key:(.key + "-" +(.value.id|tostring)), value:.value}) | from_entries'
```

If there is a shorter way to do it (maybe using `with_entries`), I would be happy to know.

Comment: `with_entries(...)` is the exact same as `to_entries | map(...) | from_entries`. Additionally, you can just set the key with `=` or `|=`. Finally, you can do string interpolation with `\(expr)`. 
So, you can just do `jq 'with_entries(.key = "\(.key)-\(.value.id)")'`

Answer (score 0):

```
jq '[.[] | { fruit2: .veg, other_key: .other_orig_key }]'
```

check [this example](https://jqplay.org/s/gs9pLKloGWX)