# jq JSON key change assignment not working

Tags: json, jq

jq key assignment is not working.

I tried what was here for my use case.
[Using jq how can I replace the name of a key with something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43522133/using-jq-how-can-i-replace-the-name-of-a-key-with-something-else)

in this case I want to change `id` to item_id`.

```
jq '.item[]  | select(.closed == false) | select(.id == "1234") |  .["id"] = .["item_id"] | .' data.json | less
```

the result does not error but "id" gets a value of `null` and there is not key called `item_id`. so there is something I am not getting right about assignment of the key.

Comment: See the other answer to that question, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just delete the old field using `del`, and add another one using [object construction](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectConstruction%3A%7B%7D):

```bash
jq '.item[]  | select(.closed == false and .id == "1234") | del(.id) + {item_id: .id}' data.json
```

Or use `with_entries` to "rename" the old field:

```bash
jq '.item[]  | select(.closed == false and .id == "1234") | with_entries(select(.key == "id").key = "item_id")' data.json
```